# Create the ID by nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence) but the ID is not in the sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a problem for a long while but still can't find out the solution.

I have a table be like in PostgreSQL

```
CREAT TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table
(
    ID bigserial NOT NULL,
    Fruit varchar(256) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

And then I use the below this nextval with pg_get_serial_sequence to create an ID for each fruit column

```
select 
    nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table', 'ID')) END AS ID,
    fruit
from
    fruit_source_table
```

This is what I want (The order of Fruit column must be Apple, Cherry, Banana)

| ID | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Cherry |
| 3 | Banana |

But the result is

| ID | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Apple |
| 3 | Cherry |
| 1 | Banana |

My question is how to make the ID from 1 to 3 instead of disorder ID? (The order of Fruit is correct from the source table but the ID is not in order)

Comment: Rows have no intrinsic order in a table. If you want to order rows then you need to use an ORDER BY clause

Comment: Use row_number() if you want a row number, not a sequence generator.

Comment: Why does it matter which row has which sequence number?

Comment: Hi @NickW As this is some kind of business requirment so that the he sequence of Fruit column should be fixed

Comment: "Fixed" how exactly? Where does the order come from?

Comment: Hi @ErwinBrandstetter The order of Fruit is coming from business document. This is the downstream user requiring.

Comment: The **only** way to get a specific (deterministic) sequence is with *order by*. You **cannot** have a deterministic order of rows stored. One possibility is to create an additional column containing the desired/required sequencing then order by that column.

Comment: *"from business document"* Clarifies nothing, yet. How does the order enter your query?

Answer (score 0):

The artificially generated primary keys will be assigned in the order that you insert the rows into the table. So either make sure that you insert the rows in the correct order or (better) add another column `fruitrank real` that defines the order.  With the additional column you can reorder the rows when necessary or insert new rows in an arbitrary position in the sorting order.